# linux c - get server hostname?

Tags: c

Does anyone know a function to get the hostname of the linux server? I don't really want to have to include any headers or compile other libraries, hoping there is a function built in by default. I'm new to c :)

Comment: There are no builtin functions in C. You will have to include headers and/or link libraries. Are you talking about the server running on your machine or another?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

like [gethostname()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname) ?

That's the name of the machine on which your app is running.

Or read from

```
/proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

**Update**

Simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

    char hostname[1024];
    gethostname(hostname, 1024);

    puts(hostname);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of how to print it the screen? Don't laugh, but I've tried the following and it errors out :)
int gethostname(char *name, size_t len);
printf("%s\n",name);

Comment: You should pass `sizeof(hostname) -1` as length to `gethostname()`. Otherwise you might end up with no null-termination if truncation occurs. According to my manpage: "POSIX.1 says that if such truncation occurs, then it is unspecified whether the returned buffer includes a terminating null byte."

Comment: @scai In order for that to do any good, you'd also want to make sure `hostname[1023]` is null. In which case, you could just continue to pass `sizeof(hostname)` to it and then set `hostname[1023]` to null after `gethostname()` returns.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the answer from Alain Pannetier, you can spare a few bytes by using HOST_NAME_MAX:

```
#include <limits.h>
...
  char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX+1];
  gethostname(hostname, HOST_NAME_MAX+1);
...
```