# Linux C API for getting remote server's hostname?

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way(a C API?), using which I can get the hostname of a remote server. Something like [gethostname()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5190553/5701173) but having an IP address as an argument.

I know about [getnameinfo() and getaddrinfo()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/235639/185560), however I don't want the hostname used in the DNS server. I want the hostname which you get when you use the hostname command in linux. I have a feeling that it might be impossible to do without knowing the login credentials of that remote server but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: IIRC only the DNS server will answer with the name of a machine, but not the machine.

Comment: How would you  do what you want from command line (in the computer where you would run you C program)?

Comment: To run a command on a server over the internet, you needs some kind of deamon to run the command for you. This could be `sshd`, `httpd`, etc. So the question you must answer is what daemon is running (or that you could setup) on the machine that you could use?

Comment: I won't have the credentials of that server to run ssh. I'll just have the IP. Just wanted to know if something like gethostname(char* ip, char* hostname, size_t len) exists?

Comment: I think you are asking how to use reverse DNS lookup from a program. For that the question asked by hyde above is important, because the source of the IP address needs to be known. Is it from commandline parameter? Is it user input? Is it the IP address used for an existing connection? You need to specify this in your question. Please [edit] and explain where the IP address to use is coming from.

Comment: There's no standard protocol for this, so nothing for an API to use.

Comment: Re "*Just wanted to know if something like `gethostname(char* ip, char* hostname, size_t len)` exists?*", Sure there is. There are lots of way of doing that. The question you must answer is what daemon is running (or that you could setup) on the machine that you could use? You can't get information from a machine before first reaching out to it!

Comment: @hyde I haven't understood that question. I just wanted to know if there's any C API like gethostname which takes the IP as an argument. The IP will be a string.

Comment: @ikegami is there any method by which I can get the hostname without knowing the user credential of that remote server? And please note that I don't want the hostname from the DNS. I want the string which you get when you call the gethostname() C API.

Comment: Sure. You can absolutely have a daemon that serves responses without requiring credentials. (You did that when you loaded this login page for this site, for example.) But we don't know what's running on the machine, so *you* need to tell *us*

Comment: @ikegami Please excuse me if this sounds naive but I wanted to know if an API exists which doesn't require you to setup any daemon on that remote server and still it could fetch you the hostname.

Comment: No, you can't get information from another machine without talking to that machine. That's impossible.

Comment: @ikegami Well I was naively(maybe stupidly) hoping that that wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can query DNS for hostnames, there's no standard protocol to ask a machine (an interface, really) what it calls itself (if it does even have a name for itself - that's not mandatory).

You'd need to implement and deploy a simple server program onto all the hosts you're interested in (it could be something as simple as adding a line to `/etc/inetd.conf` to run `/bin/hostname` if it's a Unix-like system), and a client library to access it.